# Replace the code in the Eclipse environment

Tags: android, eclipse

Instead of a few lines of code
What method can be used?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);    
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuAPI);
```

I know that both `DefaultHttpClient` and `HttpConnectionParams` are deprecated.

I am using the Eclipse development environment.

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported and `DefaultHttpClient` has been gradually phased out since Android 2.3. You should really consider to modernize your code base and tooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
```

> This interface was deprecated in API level 22. Please use
>   openConnection() instead. Please visit this webpage for further
>   details.

you should switch to java.net.URL.openConnection().

```
URL url = new URL("http://some-server");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

and

[`RequestConfig.Builder`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html),inside [`org.apache.http.client.config`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/package-summary.html) which has `setConnectTimeout.`

**still want to use deprecated library**

`org.apache.http.legacy.jar` is inside your sdk platform, add to your build path and use.

Comment: thanks so much but I did not catch //RequestConfig.Builder,inside org.apache.http.config which has setConnectTimeout.

Comment: HttpConnectionParams is deprecated so use setConnectTimeout() of RequestConfig.Builder class.